# Presigned URL credentials for put command did return true as it supposed to

Tags: node.js, reactjs, cors, digital-ocean

`Access-Control-Allow-Credentials` header's value returned from the Digital Ocean response is `' '` (empty string), but it supposed to be `true`.

I'm trying to create a presigned put url and send it to my front end React application to upload the files from there, but I got the error shown in [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o59Rn.png) picture.

**Here is my server-side s3 client configurations:**

```js
const { PutObjectCommand, S3Client } = require('@aws-sdk/client-s3');
const { getSignedUrl } = require('@aws-sdk/s3-request-presigner');

const { config } = require('../../config/environments');

const { doKey, doSecret } = config;

const s3 = new S3Client({
  endpoint: 'https://chatty-bucket.fra1.digitaloceanspaces.com',
  credentials: {
    accessKeyId: doKey,
    secretAccessKey: doSecret,
  },
  region: 'fra1',
});

const generatePresignedUrl = async (fileType, fileName) => {
  try {
    const command = new PutObjectCommand({
      Bucket: '_static',
      Key: fileName,
      ACL: 'public',
    });

    const url = await getSignedUrl(s3, command, {
      expiresIn: 3600,
    });

    return url;
  } catch (error) {
    return error;
  }
};

module.exports = { generatePresignedUrl };
```

**And here is my axios request:**

```js
await axios.put(data?.data.data.url, files[0], {
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': files[0].type,
          'Content-Length': new Blob([files[0]]).length,
          'x-amz-acl': 'public-read',
          'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': 'http://localhost:5173',
        },
        withCredentials: true,
      });
```

And [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gnk12.png) is my my CORS configurations in the DO bucket settings

*Note:* I'm making the request from my local host.

Comment: Hi, the use of images for code /errors  creates a lot of problems. Please read [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/7353417). Thank you

Comment: You should remove CORS headers from your request. They're meaningless. The header you specified is set by the server, and browser headers are set by browsers automatically.

Comment: along with what @Evert said, see: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS/Errors/CORSMIssingAllowCredentials for this exact error and the "why"